Stacked boxplot
I am trying to create a stacked boxplot where each row represents a city and each column a land use (LU). Also, I want each pair of boxplots to have it's own range on the y-axis much like the one in the attached image below:

I managed to get close to the desired outcome, but I can't set the range of values in each boxplot. Some empty panels are intentionally empty.

As you can see in my plot above, there is a "fixed" range of values for each row and this causes many boxplots to kinda disappear.
How can I set each pair of boxplots to have it's own range? I think it's called faceting, but I am not sure about this so I don't want to confuse someone.
library(ggplot2)

plot_data <- do.call(rbind, lapply(names(data_list), function(city) {
  do.call(rbind, lapply(names(data_list[[city]]), function(lu) {
    prepare_data(data_list[[city]][[lu]], city, lu, lockdown_dates[[city]])
  }))
}))

plot_data$LU <- gsub("^(.)", "\\U\\1", plot_data$LU, perl = TRUE)
plot_data$City <- gsub("_", " ", plot_data$City)
plot_data$City <- gsub("^(.)", "\\U\\1", plot_data$City, perl = TRUE)

plot_data$Period <- factor(plot_data$Period, levels = c("Pre", "During"))

lu_levels <- levels(plot_data$LU)
city_levels <- levels(plot_data$City)

y_breaks <- seq(from = min(plot_data$trend), to = max(plot_data$trend), length.out = length(city_levels) + 1)

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Period, y = trend)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(City ~ LU, 
             scales = "free_y"
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text.y = element_text(size = 10, 
                                angle = 270,
                                vjust = 0.5,
                                hjust = 0.5),
    strip.text.x = element_text(size = 10),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, linewidth = 0.5),
    axis.line.y.right = element_blank(),
    axis.line.x.top = element_blank(),
    panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"),
    axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
    plot.title = element_blank()
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "Sensitivity period",
    y = "Weighted average radiance"
  )

Session info
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.2 (2024-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.5.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] labeling_0.4.3    R6_2.5.1          tidyselect_1.2.1  farver_2.1.2      magrittr_2.0.3    gtable_0.3.6     
 [7] glue_1.8.0        tibble_3.2.1      pkgconfig_2.0.3   generics_0.1.3    dplyr_1.1.4       lifecycle_1.0.4  
[13] cli_3.6.3         scales_1.3.0      grid_4.4.2        vctrs_0.6.5       withr_3.0.2       compiler_4.4.2   
[19] rstudioapi_0.17.1 tools_4.4.2       munsell_0.5.1     pillar_1.10.0     colorspace_2.1-1  rlang_1.1.4

And a sample dataset:
> dput(plot_data)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17532, 17563, 17591, 17622, 
17652, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 17563, 17591, 17622, 
17652, 17683, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 17532, 17563, 
17591, 17622, 17652, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 17532, 
17563, 17591, 17622, 17652, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444
), class = "Date"), trend = c(57.3677749905009, 58.0596074609876, 
58.7514399314743, 59.4736342351304, 60.1958285387865, 61.0104910239989, 
60.5590244438097, 60.1075578636205, 60.0843216641987, 60.0610854647769, 
60.7329151572886, 61.4051375371955, 62.0773599171023, 62.7460168575561, 
63.4146737980098, 58.670962847084, 57.4858638723977, 56.4629549980364, 
55.4400461236752, 54.9039261177204, 58.0711789520474, 57.8877846474122, 
57.7043903427771, 57.5178399049509, 57.3312894671247, 53.9585696566587, 
53.7663355864871, 53.5741015163154, 53.2453651266067, 52.916628736898, 
39.3423049815325, 39.2561334213596, 39.1699618611867, 39.0888822657093, 
39.007802670232, 36.898768785514, 36.8309526943152, 36.7631366031163, 
36.7180528611537, 36.6729691191911), Period = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Pre", "During"), class = "factor"), 
    City = c("Cairo", "Cairo", "Cairo", "Cairo", "Cairo", "Cairo", 
    "Cairo", "Cairo", "Cairo", "Cairo", "Cairo", "Cairo", "Cairo", 
    "Cairo", "Cairo", "Cairo", "Cairo", "Cairo", "Cairo", "Cairo", 
    "Delhi", "Delhi", "Delhi", "Delhi", "Delhi", "Delhi", "Delhi", 
    "Delhi", "Delhi", "Delhi", "Delhi", "Delhi", "Delhi", "Delhi", 
    "Delhi", "Delhi", "Delhi", "Delhi", "Delhi", "Delhi"), LU = c("Commercial", 
    "Commercial", "Commercial", "Commercial", "Commercial", "Commercial", 
    "Commercial", "Commercial", "Commercial", "Commercial", "Industrial", 
    "Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial", 
    "Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial", "Commercial", 
    "Commercial", "Commercial", "Commercial", "Commercial", "Commercial", 
    "Commercial", "Commercial", "Commercial", "Commercial", "Industrial", 
    "Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial", 
    "Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -40L), groups = structure(list(
    City = c("Cairo", "Cairo", "Cairo", "Cairo", "Delhi", "Delhi", 
    "Delhi", "Delhi"), LU = c("Commercial", "Commercial", "Industrial", 
    "Industrial", "Commercial", "Commercial", "Industrial", "Industrial"
    ), Period = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("Pre", 
    "During"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1:5, 
        6:10, 11:15, 16:20, 21:25, 26:30, 31:35, 36:40), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -8L), .drop = TRUE, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))

EDIT
If I use facet_wrap instead of facet_grid, although it gives each facet an independent range, it ruins the structure of the plot.


What happens if you swap out facet_grid for facet_wrap?

It does give each axis an independent range, it ruing the structure of the plot. I edited my question to show what happen when I use facet_wrap.

For facet_grid, the whole row shares a y-axis. You can probably use ggh4x::facet_grid2(). Look at the last example.

Nice! I wasn't aware of the ggh4x package. I will post the complete code any moment now.
